# UISearchBar works on simulator but doesn't work on device

Tags: ios, uikit, ios-simulator, device, uisearchbar

I'm using an `UISearchBar` in my app. When I run on simulator everything is fine. On device does not work. On device, my searchbar frame is changing but keybord doesn't show. `NSlog`s are working. My code is here:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    NSLog(@"wrote");
}

-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    [self.mySearchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,mySearchBar.frame.size.width,mySearchBar.frame.size.height)];
    mySearchBar.showsCancelButton=TRUE;
    mySearchBar.text=@"nowwrite";
    NSLog(@"chosed");    
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    NSLog(@"cancel");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mySearchBar.delegate=self;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

and my .h file

```
@interface sehirRehberi : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *mySearchBar;
}

@property(retain, nonatomic) UISearchBar *mySearchBar;
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what is going on. Try to edit your question and add log errors. Thank you.

Comment: i havent error log. because i dont have an error. everything is seem ok. but uisearchbar doesnt working. my nslogs working but keybord doesnt seen

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about an error. It's quite strange. P.S. Class names usually start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made the view first responder? That's necessary for the keyboard to show. I'm not sure why it's working on the simulator, but you should call `[self becomeFirstResponder];` in your `viewDidLoad` method to enable the view to receive keyboard events and thus show the keyboard. When you're done (`viewWillDisappear`, etc.), just call `[self resignFirstResponder];`. I think that's your problem. It's hard to tell without more explanation/code.

Comment: i called becomefirstresponder in a clicked method: like this clickedShouldBeganTextEdit. is it wrong?  do i have to  call it in viewdidload?.(Sory  i am not on my pc now)

Comment: Yes, calling it when `viewDidLoad` or when the `viewDidAppear` is something that should make it work.

Comment: Really? Damn. To diagnose the problem more, I need more code. Everything looks fine in what you have written. What version is iOS on the device?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem that 'UISearchBar' appeared in Simulator but not in actual device. I fixed the issue by calling Constructor with NibName as I placed the UISearchBar in nib file.

```
[MyUITableViewController initWithNibName:@"MyUITableViewController" bundle:nil];
```